# Tensorflow RGB-D Training

Tags: tensorflow, computer-vision

I have RGB-D (color&depth) images for given scene. I would like to use tensorflow to train a classification model based on pre-trained network such as inception. As far as I understood, these pre-trained models were built using 3-channel RGB images.  However, the inclusion of 4th channel cannot be handled.

How do I use RGB-D images directly? Do I need to pre-process the images, and seperate RGB and D, if so, how do I use the D (1-channel) alone?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use a pre-trained model you can only use RGB, as they were only trained to understand RGB. In this case, it is as you said: separate them and discard depth.

To use a 4 channel image like this you would need to retrain the network from scratch rather than loading a pre-trained set of weights.

You will probably get good results using the same architecture as is used for 3 channel images (save for the minor change required to support the 4 channel input), so retraining shouldn't be terribly hard.